Beyond polynomial speedups in diagonal entries estimation
Consider the task of estimating the diagonal entries of the power of a real sparse matrix A with $N = 2^n$ rows:

Input: $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ with $A = A^\top$ and $s$-sparse and row-efficient, $s = \mathrm{poly}\log(N)$; $p = \mathrm{poly}\log N$; $\epsilon = 1/\mathrm{poly}\log(N)$; $j \in 1, \ldots, N$; $\chi \in [- \lVert A \rVert^p, \lVert A \rVert^p]$.
Output: YES if $(A)_{jj} \ge \chi + \epsilon \lVert A \rVert^p$, NO if $(A)_{jj} \le \chi - \epsilon \lVert A \rVert^p$

The work [1] A Simple PromiseBQP-complete Matrix Problem shows that such a problem is (Promise)QBP-complete. They also present an algorithm running in polynomial time with respect to $n, p, 1/\epsilon$ and estimating the quantity up to the additive error $\epsilon \lVert A \rVert^p$.
The work [2] The Quantum Complexity of Computing Schatten p-norms, Appendix B shows a classical algorithm based on random walks running in polynomial time with respect to $n, p, 1/\epsilon$ up to a possibly larger additive error, $\epsilon s^p \lVert A \rVert^p_\text{max}$, and with a constant failure probability. Here, $\lVert A \rVert$ is the operator norm and $\lVert A \rVert_\text{max} = \max_{i,j} |(A)_{i,j}|$ the absolute value of the largest entry of $A$.
Furthermore, [2, Section 4.2] suggests (in relation to the intimately related task of estimating $\mathrm{Trace}[A^p]/2^n$, which is DQC1-hard) that a quadratic speedup is possible (and the explicit construction of an example is shown), not sure anything beyond that.
If we focus uniquely on the first task, i.e. estimating the diagonal entris with a precision of $\epsilon \lVert A \rVert^p$, can we prove that (due to the BQP completeness of the task) there has to be a superpolynomial separation between the performance of the quantum algorithm proposed and any classical algorithm (or at least with the one classical algorithm shown), and can we construct such instances? Can a possible way forward be to focus on instances such that the ratio between the precision of the quantum and classical approach is particularly high, $\frac{\epsilon s^p \lVert A \rVert^p_\text{max}}{\epsilon \lVert A \rVert^p} \in \Omega(n^{\log n}), \Omega(\exp n)$, even though it does not rule out that another classical algorithm can beat these performance? -- these instances might be obtained by fixing the sparsity $s = O(n)$, power $p = O(n)$, and using $\lVert A \rVert \le \sqrt{s} \lVert A \rVert_\text{max}$.

You might also find value in Janzing and Wocjan’s follow up to [1], based on differences in the number of (classical) walks here . https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0610235

I think under the pretty standard assumption that BPP$\subsetneq$BQP, there is likely a superpolynomial improvement with a quantum algorithm as to the accuracy of the (additive) error of the estimate of a diagonal entry $A_{jj}$, especially when, as you say, the operator norm $\Vert A\Vert$ is much less than $\Vert A\Vert_\max$.
One particular problem that I like to think a lot about is when $A$ is the adjacency matrix of the Cayley graph of the Rubik's cube - $(A^p)_{jj}$ counts the number of $p$-length walks starting at node $j$, walking $p$ steps, and returning back to node $j$. Here $A$ has $18$ generators - a $90^\circ$ clockwise turn, a $180^\circ$ clockwise turn, and a $270^\circ$ clockwise (or $90^\circ$ counter-clockwise) turn, for each of the $6$ faces.  In this case I'm pretty sure the sparsity factor $s=18$, while the operator norm $\Vert A\Vert$ is also $18$, and the quantum algorithm doesn't clearly give much advantage over the classical, for counting the number of $p$-length reentrant walks.
But one question about the Rubik's cube that likely does have a superpolynomial advantage is in counting a difference in the number of $p$-length walks that start at $j$ and end at $j$, versus those that start at $j$ and end at another node $k$. The classical algorithm of Cade and Montanaro, I think, fails to account for this difference.  I also think your idea of restricting $\Vert A\Vert\le\sqrt s \Vert A\Vert_\max$ secures a superpolynomial quantum advantage (assuming BPP$\subsetneq$BQP).
The Cade and Montanaro paper is very nice and thanks for pointing it out - I had thought of their classical algorithm for counting the number of walks on an unweighted graph up to $\epsilon s^p\Vert A\Vert_\max^p$ but didn't realize that the same could be said for a weighted graph - even with negative weights.
One classical algorithm on an unweighted, sparse graph that Cade and Montanaro don't mention is to hash all the strings $(n_0,n_1,\ldots,n_p)$ that walk back to node $j$, and to find a string that hashes onto $\bar 0$. Alas, this algorithm is (1) in BPP$^\mathsf{NP}$ and not likely in P or BPP and hence is not likely classically efficient, (2) only up to multiplicative error, and (3) likely doesn't work for weighted graphs with entries in $\mathbb R^-$.
